# tshark - Automatically set YES when asked "Should non-superusers be able to capture packets"

Tags: apt, docker, wireshark

Thank you for your incredible work here.

I'd like to install tshark in a docker container, and while writing a dockerfile I was wondering if there's a way to automatically set YES when asked to *manually* set if non-superusers should be allowed to capture or not.

[image]

Of course I tried

```
sudo apt install tshark -y
```

but it still asks me to insert the answer.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

The following command does the trick:

```
sudo apt install -y --allow-change-held-packages tshark
```

If this does not work, use the deprecated option:

```
sudo apt install -y --force-yes tshark
```

[See the manual for more help](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/apt/apt-get.8.en.html)

If nothing works, try this on the separate line (do not chain it with other packages):

```
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y tshark
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to do this, for example, in a Docker container is:

```
echo "wireshark-common wireshark-common/install-setuid boolean true" | sudo debconf-set-selections
```

Followed by:

```
apt-get -y install tshark
```